# How to pass php variable to function add_cart_item_data to modify product price in wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, divi

I need to add an extra to price in woocommerce product with checkbox option, I get php value to add `$num = 5` from database.
This is working only with numbers, but not with php variable outside the scope. I use global but no results.
I couldn't add anything afterwards bracket `}`.

Here is my code :

```
 $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT TextBox3 FROM wprd1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
 $sth->execute();
 $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $num = $result['TextBox3'];
 echo $num;
 global $num;       

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
 
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {    
    global $num;
     // get product id & price
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $price = $product->get_price();
    // extra pack checkbox
    if( ! empty( $_POST['extra_pack'] ) ) {
       
        $cart_item_data['new_price'] = $price + 15 + $num;
    }
return $cart_item_data;
}
```

[image]

The final result is current price `$price + 15` but `$num`is ignored.

Comment: What is the execution context of the first block of code, did that even run, when you are making an AJAX request? And why are you not making this database query _in_ `add_cart_item_data` then?

Comment: I had done this before, but without the database connection configuration, thinking it will make a duplicate, so I put it in and it works! Your comment re-motivated me. Thanks CBroe.